# Linked List in the same Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new at C++, and I'm dealing with the Linked List. However, I'm confused that, while I'm writing a Linked List class. I'm trying to write a code for soccer league. I'm trying to hold each team in a linked list and since each team has players I would like to store them also in a linked list. So the linked list class should have a member to point a linked list which is the same property with the class I'm writing. Can it be possible?

Comment: You can have a pointer to `LinkedList` inside `LinkedList` class.You cannot have `LinkedList` object inside `LinkedList` class, that would lead to an object of infinite size. On a side note you can simple use `std::list`.

Comment: what Linked List implementation are you using? Are you using `std::list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A node of the teams list would contain a list of players. If you can't use `std::list`:

```
struct Player
{
    Player* nextPlayer;
};

struct Team
{
    Team* nextTeam;
    Player* firstPlayer;
};
```

I'm pretty sure though that a list is not the optimal structure to model this.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the following structure as you may not want to use players and teams always in a list:

```
struct PlayerNode
{
    Player* item;
    PlayerNode* nextNode;
};

struct TeamNode
{
    Team* item;
    TeamNode* nextNode;
};

struct Team {
    // ...
    PlayerNode* firstPlayer;
};
```

This allows you to use a team or a player as a standalone object (not connected to other teams/players).
But within a team you can also access its players, which I guess is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ then use STL instead. I am explaining one example with vector

Suppose this is the heirarchy
You have 2 League League1, League2
each have 2 teams Team1, Team2
each team has 10 players P1, P2

All the players of one team can be stored in a vector named temp_team
All temp_team can be pushed to vector named temp_league
All temp_league vector can be pushed to vector named footBall, League, watever.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is often referred to as a nested linked list or a linked list of linked lists. In your case, you want to create a soccer league, where each team has its own linked list of players.
In this example, the Team class has a linked list of players, and the League class has a linked list of teams. Each team can have its own players, and the league can have multiple teams. The addPlayer method is used to add players to a team, and the addTeam method is used to add teams to the league. The displayPlayers and displayTeams methods are used to display the players and teams, respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
    string name;
    int age;

    Player(const string& playerName, int playerAge) : name(playerName), age(playerAge) {}
};

class Team {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        Player player;
        Node* next;

        Node(const Player& player) : player(player), next(nullptr) {}
    };

    Node* head;

public:
    Team() : head(nullptr) {}

    void addPlayer(const Player& player) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(player);
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    void displayPlayers() {
        Node* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            cout << "Player: " << current->player.name << ", Age: " << current->player.age << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};

class League {
private:
    class TeamNode {
    public:
        Team team;
        TeamNode* next;

        TeamNode(const Team& team) : team(team), next(nullptr) {}
    };

    TeamNode* head;

public:
    League() : head(nullptr) {}

    void addTeam(const Team& team) {
        TeamNode* newNode = new TeamNode(team);
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    void displayTeams() {
        TeamNode* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            cout << "Team:" << endl;
            current->team.displayPlayers();
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // Create players
    Player player1("John", 25);
    Player player2("Alice", 22);
    Player player3("Bob", 28);

    // Create a team and add players
    Team team1;
    team1.addPlayer(player1);
    team1.addPlayer(player2);

    // Create another team and add players
    Team team2;
    team2.addPlayer(player3);

    // Create a league and add teams
    League league;
    league.addTeam(team1);
    league.addTeam(team2);

    // Display teams and players in the league
    league.displayTeams();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You allocate memory using ``new``, but never free it with ``delete``. You classes seem to need a destructor to do this (and should also ahve a copy constructor and a user-defined copy assignment operator, cf. "rule of three" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)